# How do I get make to run a command that uses a make variable in it to create an azure service principal

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have the following rule in my Makefile:

```
setSPRole:
    az role assignment create --assignee $(appId) --scope $(az acr show --name $(acr_name) --query id --output tsv) --role acrpush
```

At the top of the file I have
`include .env`
so that I can use appId and acr_name

however when I run `make setSPRole` the result I get is:
`az role assignment create --assignee "MY_ACTUAL_APP_ID" --scope  --role acrpush`

As you can see the scope is empty but the appId gets filled in correctly.
**How do I get scope to use the value of the az acr show command?**

What I have tried:
I have tried assigning the value and then using it on the next line like so:

```
setSPRole:
    ACR_REG_ID = az acr show --name $(acr_name) --query id --output tsv; \
    az role assignment create --assignee $(appId) --scope $(ACR_REG_ID) --role acrpush
```

but that did not work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recipes in make rules are shell scripts.  Make invokes the shell to run them.  So, the command you put into a recipe (indented with a TAB) must be a valid shell command.

Knowing that, maybe you can see why your second example doesn't work: that's not a valid shell script (if you type it at your shell prompt you'll get the same error you get when make runs it).

However make uses the `$` prefix for its own variable (and function, in GNU make) expansion.  So text like `$(foo)` or `${foo}` is expanded by make, before invoking the shell, and it sends the result of the expansion to the shell to be run.

Knowing that, maybe you can see why your first example doesn't work: the string `$(az acr show ...)` is considered a long make variable name, which has never been set, so it expands to the empty string.

In a make recipe if you want to hide the `$` from make so it's passed to the shell instead, you escape it by writing it twice: `$$(az acr show ...)`.

Comment: Thanks, this was a great explanation of how make works. For future users I had to add a second $ before ```az acr show...``` but I had to leave the single dollar sign before ```acr_name``` since I wanted that to be expanded by make.